# How Can I estimate pglm across 5 imputed panel count datasets for mitools analysis?

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, glm

I am currently using `mitools` to analyze 5 imputed datasets (I used Amelia). The unit of analysis is country-year. Each dataset has over 3600 observations. The dependent variable of interest for all analyses is a lagged count variable.

Given the nature of the data (panel & count), I decided to use the `pglm package`. I have been using the following code to attempt to estimate pglm models across all five imputed datasets, in order to combine those estimates with mitools:

```
setwd("C:/Desktop")

library(mitools)
library(pglm)

#The data.dir code below establishes where the files are located
data.dir <- "C:/Desktop"

#The imputationList function combines all 5 imputed gtot datasets into one object
#called allgtot
allcountdata <- imputationList(lapply(list.files(data.dir, pattern = "panelcount.\\.dta", full=TRUE),read.dta, warn.missing.labels=FALSE))

#To see if the combining was successful
allcountdata

#Lets see if all of the column names are still there
colnames(allcountdata)


count_mitools<-pglm(count_lag ~     
                        HROsec
                        + hrofilled
                        + physint
                        + democracy
                        + log(PopTotal)
                        + GDPpercapita
                        + cell
                        + gini
                        + polity2
                        + CivilWar
                        + milper
                        + elp
                        + factor(year),
                        allcountdata,
                        family="negbin",
                        model="within", 
                        print.level=0,
                        method="nr",
                        index=c("cowcode", "year"))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in is.finite(x[[i]]) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I attempt to coerce the list object into a dataframe as follows:

```
as.data.frame(allcountdata)
```

However, R states that I cannot do so.

What can I do to make the pglm estimation work?

If I cannot use pglm, what are alternatives models (and corresponding R packages) suitable for panel count data regression analysis that are either (preferably both):

a) compatible with a mitools analysis
 b) accepting of list objects for estimation

I am providing a link to a compressed zipfile containing all five imputed datasets I am working with [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kaceda0fi1kphpa/PanelCountImputedData.zip).

Comment: I think you just want to use the function `MIcombine`, which will give you a confidence interval. Your eagerness to use the "stars" only hardens my wish that R Core would finally remove them entirely from things like `summary.lm` etc.

Comment: @joran - And end up with software where it's impossible to achieve significance?! Who would ever use R then!?

Comment: You are being a bit too harsh. I think R community needs to do more to educate users the meaning of significance and why we should be looking at intervals anyway. Suggestions?

Comment: Is MIcombine reporting a 95% confidence interval?

Comment: @joran: I believe R Core is planning to remove stars. In the meantime you can set them "off" with `options("show.signif.stars"=FALSE)`.